# transform linewise output from grep into inline, space separated format

Tags: bash

- I am getting some linewise output from grep like ...

```
value1
value2
value3
```

- in order to filling a variable for a bash script I need to transform this into inline format like `('value1' 'value2' 'value3')` though.

In reality there are more then 40 values, so I am looking for an automated workflow rather then just doing it manually.

how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pipe your output to something like:

```
sed "s/$/\'/"  | sed "s/^/\'/" | tr  '\n' ' ' ;echo
```

Answer (score 1):

> - in order to filling a variable for a bash script I need to transform this into inline format like ('value1' 'value2' 'value3')
>   though.

To fill an indexed array variable with lines from the output of a `grep` command in bash, you can use the `readarray` (aka `mapfile`) shell builtin:

```
readarray -t arr < <(grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...])
```

Adding literal quotes is not necessary.